# HERE SDK: LocationManager requestLocationUpdates() RuntimeException

Tags: android, here-api, locationmanager

I'm using HERE Maps SDK and after calling `navigationManager.startNavigation()` I'm getting this exception in logs, SOMETIMES:

```
LocationManager: [LocationManager] requestLocationUpdates(), 
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:1013)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:595)
        at com.nokia.maps.ef.i(PlatformLocation.java:435)
        at com.nokia.maps.ef.start(PlatformLocation.java:112)
        at com.nokia.maps.PositioningManagerImpl.a(PositioningManagerImpl.java:192)
        at com.here.android.mpa.common.PositioningManager.start(PositioningManager.java:212)
        at com.nokia.maps.NavigationManagerImpl.a(NavigationManagerImpl.java:1785)
        at com.nokia.maps.NavigationManagerImpl.a(NavigationManagerImpl.java:1063)
        at com.here.android.mpa.guidance.NavigationManager.startNavigation(NavigationManager.java:1272)
        ...
```

Looks like the SDK is catching it because try/catch doesn't get it and nothing crashes, response is still `NavigationManager.Error.NONE` but navigation doesn't start.

Not sure what triggers it but the app may work fine for days and then this shows up and for few minutes or hours I can't get the navigation to work.

This exception occurs only sometimes, when the app tries to get a location from the SDK, but then it's for every single request for a certain time.

Has anybody encountered this ? I have no idea how to handle this other than setting a timer to check whether I'm getting any location updates.

Comment: Please provide us your device version ad sdk version details for us to help you better.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport this was on Android SDK 3.9.0 but the same happens on 3.8.0 and 3.7.0. Sometimes pause()/resume() helps, not always.

Comment: Please provide us the code or steps to reproduce (sample app). Is there only a specified exception in the log, or does it contain something else?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I'll try to put together a sample but it's quite a bit of code to get to the navigationManager.startNavigation() call. It's only in logs, contains only stacktrace, what I pasted is everything that happens from .startNavigation(). sometimes the app continues with some location after few seconds sometimes it just sits there without any updates after this appearing in the log

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for `LocationManager` [describes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/LocationManager.java#588) that `requestLocationUpdates` throws two types of exceptions - `IllegalArgumentException` and `SecurityException`. 
Maybe some vendor added its own undocumented logic that throws `RuntimeException`.

As a dirty fix, you could try stop/start requestLocationUpdates like that:

```
PositioningManager.start(LocationMethod.NETWORK); // will stop updates for LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
PositioningManager.start(LocationMethod.GPS); // will stop updates for LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
PositioningManager.start(LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK); // will start updates for both
```

Secondly, if you have appropriate permission, you can try setting HERE location data source, like that:

```
//SDK will use custom algorithm to calculate device location
//and Android's LocationManager will not be used
PositioningManager.setDataSource(LocationDataSourceHERE.getInstance());
```

If you provide more info, like device, preconditions when it is happening, do other apps like Google Map can detect your location etc, maybe then it can be fixed.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. It's on Nokia 6 with android 9 right now. That exception is not thrown, just logged. try/catch doesn't catch anything and error response is still NONE. Google Maps shows my location perfectly.

Comment: There is an overloaded method `requestLocationUpdates` which tells: *throws RuntimeException if the calling thread has no Looper*. I've found these entries in my log as well. Don't know exactly if there's a bad effect...

Comment: I've got the same on Nokia 7 running Android 9 and I am calling that from a Handler with a main Looper. I don't observe any side effects though.

Comment: Facing same exception on Nokia 6.1 plus with android 9. As this is android one I'd expect it to be stock, the vendors shouldn't be adding there own implementation for common framework components.